# PHP: fopen - Permission denied - chmod 777 already done

Tags: php, permissions, permission-denied

I am setting up a new CentOS 6.6 machine running PHP 5.5 and migrating our site to the server but am getting the error in my httpd error log:

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(/ssd-media/www/app/storage/logs/laravel.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /ssd-media/www/index.php on line
```

I have already checked and the httpd process is being run as the user/group "apache" and have done the `chmod -R 775 storage` and verified that the file has the right user / group configured and permissions and then ran the following code:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("/ssd-media/www/app/storage/logs/laravel.log", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "test\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

I have moved the DocumentRoot to /ssd-media/www which is not where CentOS is installed, it is an SSD RAID that is only for the apache / mysql files. Other than that it is a fairly simple configuration for which I followed this guide:
https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/

What other reasons would I get a permissions denied on that file? I tried 777 permissions as well to no avail.

Comment: Do all folders in that path have correct permissions? eg. `/ssd-media`, `/ssd-media/www`, `/ssd-media/www/app` etc. Tried temporary disabling SELinux to see if that helps?

Comment: To add to @Jono20201's comment, the apache user would need "execute" permissions on each folder in that path.

Comment: @Jono20201 Great tip Jono, I had never looked at SELinux before and it was enabled and preventing it from executing. It works now but I will do some research on how to properly configure it without just disabling it.

Comment: @Alan No problem, glad I could help. SELinux was a pain for me when I first discovered it too, and it still tricks me sometimes!